# Principal bundles on 3-manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

If G is a simply connected Lie Group then why is every G-bundle over an orientable 3-manifold trivial? (Why is orientability important?)

Comment: Think about what the clutching maps are like. This is technically simplest in the classifying space formalism for bundles, your bundle is the pull-back of its classifying map $f:M\to BG$. Your assumptions are saying that $BG$ has trivial $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, but all Lie groups have trivial $\pi_2$ so $BG$ has trivial $\pi_3$, so there's the standard obstruction-theory construction of a null-homotopy of $f$.

Comment: I wanted to add that orientability of a 3-manifold is enough to guarantee that the tangent bundle is trivial.  Maybe that's why you're thinking you need orientability?

Comment: So this argument shows that a principle $G$-bundle over a space $X$ is trivial provided $X$ is a CW-complex of dimension at most $3$, and $G$ is simply-connected.

Comment: It seems that this 8-years-old post should be a duplicate of the 8-month-old post because the target has much better content.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that orientability is necessary? The result is proved in lemma 4.1.1.  [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/himpel/himpel_cstheory.pdf) and I do not see where orientability is used.